# What is the possible potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

The professor asked us to do this one:

"..Determine all potentials $V(r,\theta, \phi)$ for which it is possible for find solutions of the time independent Schrodinger equation which are also eigenfunctions of the operator $L_{z}$."

I try to solve this problem by assuming separation of variables, and I get $$\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)F(\theta)e^{im_{l}\phi}$$ Unfortunately I do not know what to do next for this - should I put it into the formula $H\Phi=E\Phi$ in radial form to see whether it works? The professor give us the hint that the commutator $$[L_{z},V(r,\theta,\phi)]=0$$ I do not know how to use this relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing out $[L_z,V(r,\theta,\phi)]=0$. In other words, V has to be a function such that:
$L_zV \psi = VL_z\psi$
for absolutely any function $\psi$. Does that tell you anything about V?

Comment: Hi, so the hint is if $\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)$ is an eigenfunction of $L_{z}$, then $V(r,\theta,\phi)$ is also an eigenfunction of $L_{z}$? Is this necessarily true?

Comment: @user2597; It's not necessarily true, but it's close. When two operators commute, it's possible to select a complete set of eigenfunctions that are eigenfunctions of both. So you can *assume* that $\Phi$ is an eigenfunction of both. [Other language: Another way of saying $[L_z,V]=0$ is that $L_z$ and $V$ are compatible observables. And another way of saying this is that they form part of a complete set of commuting observables.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer your homework problem. Instead I'm going to construct a counter example to the hint $[L_{z},V]=0$, which is wrong.

Consider first, for simplicity, a spherically symmetric potential $V(r)$ and a product solution

$\Psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)e^{im\phi}$

to the time independent Schroedinger equation $(H-E)\Psi=0$, with Hamiltonian $H:=T+V$, with kinetic term $T:=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta$, and with norm $0< ||\Psi||< \infty$.

In fact, you can think of a Hydrogen-like atom, where $V(r)$ is the Coulomb potential, $R(r)$ is a Laguerre polynomial, and $\Theta(\theta)$ is an associated Legendre polynomial. If the principal quantum number $n\neq 1$ is not one, then $R(r)$ will have a radial node, i.e., there exists a radius $r_{*}>0$, such that $R(r_{*})=0$.

Now construct a new potential of the form

$\tilde{V}(r,\theta,\phi)=V(r)+\delta(r-r_{*})W(\theta,\phi)$.

The solution $\Psi$ from before will also solve the new problem $(\tilde{H}-E)\Psi=0$, where $\tilde{H}:=T+\tilde{V}$, since $R(r)\delta(r-r_{*})=0$. But $L_z$ may not commute with $\tilde{V}$.

Comment: You probably mean `\nabla` and not `\Delta` in the expression for kinetic energy. And probably want it squared, as well.

Comment: The Laplacian $\Delta:=\nabla^2$.

Comment: Ah, so. That usage is far enough from universal that it is probably worth saying so. I've never liked it myself, because I want my second order operator to *look* second order.

Comment: Dear @dmckee. Thanks for pointing it out and help improving the answer. If $\Delta$ was unclear to you, I'm sure it was unclear to others as well.

Comment: @Qmechanic: good point but this example is rather pathological.

Comment: Dear @Marek. I agree that delta function potentials are an idealization, yes, but not pathological. Allow me to remind you that they are routinely studied in many branches of physics (QM,GR,...) in completely well-posed problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic: that's only part of the problem. Bigger issue is that this potential is completely fine-tuned and unnatural. This is what pathological means. It's mathematically valid counter-example but it has no physical significance.

Comment: Dear @Marek: Firstly, I would say that, e.g., scattering in idealized delta function potentials makes *physical* sense, with well-known interpretation in terms of reflection and transmission. Secondly, I only mentioned the Hydrogen atom as a quick way to ensure the existence of radial nodes, as most are familiar with the Hydrogen solution, but the argument is more general. Thirdly, are you absolutely sure that one cannot construct a counter-example using a $C^{\infty}$ smooth potential, as you seem to prefer?

Comment: @Qmechanic: once again, I have no problem with delta functions -- if I had, I wouldn't be doing physics :) I have problem with the fact that this potential has been constructed by considering roots of another solution. *This* is what is completely unphysical. Can you construct a natural physical counterexample? I very much doubt it.

Comment: Dear @Marek: We may debate forever what is natural and what is unnatural, but Nature always makes her own choices, some of which only the future will tell.